# Form fields are not present in the form object AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I have form with a few fields, but all fields are present in form object and field with name sector is not present. Why? And how I should fix it?

```
<form name="candidateForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <div class="item item-top">
      <label>{{'Company'|translate}}*</label>
      <input company-autocompleter class="companyAutocompleterOuterSelect"
             ng-maxlength="100" name="company" ng-model="candidate.company"
             type="text" ng-change="progressUpdate()" required>
      <div class="alert alert-danger"
           ng-show="candidateForm.company.$invalid && !candidateForm.company.$pristine && candidateForm.company.$error.required == true">
          {{'Enter a company'|translate}}
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="item industry">
      <label>{{'Sector'|translate}}*</label>
      <input sector-autocomplete name="sector" type="text"
             class="select2-container form-control input-lg select2 select14 widthSelectInput1"
             required>
       <div class="alert alert-danger"
            ng-show="candidateForm.sector.$invalid && !candidateForm.sector.$pristine && candidateForm.sector.$error.required">
            {{'Enter a sector'|translate}}
       </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So, field company is present in object, but sector is not

I am not using ng-model because sector is setting inside directive:

```
element.select2({
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    placeholder: $translate.instant('Sector'),
    allowClear: true,
    data: translatedSectors,
    dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop"
}).unbind("change").on("change", function(e) {

    if(e.added) {
        if($scope.candidate) {
            $scope.candidate.sector = e.added.id;
            $scope.progressUpdate();
        } else {
            if($scope.client) {
                $scope.client.sector = e.added.id;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if($scope.candidate) {
            $scope.candidate.sector = '';
        } else {
            if($scope.client) {
                $scope.client.sector = '';
            }
        }

    }
})
```

Comment: You have a ng-model attribute in your company input but no in your sector input

Comment: if you mean that object candidate has no sector property. Then share your code how you fill data into candidate object

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sector-autocomplete` directive needs to work with the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController):

```
app.directive("sectorAutocomplete", function() {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            elem.select2({
                minimumInputLength: 0,
                placeholder: $translate.instant('Sector'),
                allowClear: true,
                data: translatedSectors,
                dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop"
            }).unbind("change").on("change", function(e) {                
                if (e.added) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(e.added.id);
                } else {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue("");
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Usage:

```
<input sector-autocomplete name="sector" type="autocomplete"
       ng-model="candidate.sector" ng-change="progressUpdate()"
       class="select2-container form-control input-lg select2 select14 widthSelectInput1"
       required />
```

The [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) is needed in order to register the control with the [`ngFormController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind input data using ng-model

```
<input sector-autocomplete name="sector" type="text"
       ng-model="candidate.sector"
       class="select2-container form-control input-lg select2 select14 widthSelectInput1"
       required>
```

Answer (score 0):

candidateForm is your validation object, the `candidate.sector` needs to be added to an ng-model